# Put unchanging code in separate memory section, to reduce OTA update size

Tags: c, memory-management, embedded, stm32, microcontroller

I am writing C code for the STM32L010RB microcontroller, which has 128 KB of flash memory where the program will reside. I want to implement over-the-air updates of this program code, and I've done this once before with an other Cortex M0+ based microcontroller. I divided the flash memory into four sections like this:

[image: SAML21E17B memory allocation]

The actual program which executes would reside in the *Main program* section, and when time comes to update it, it would contact our servers and download the new program into the *New firmware* section. A CRC check is used to ensure the integrity of the downloaded FW. A flag in the *Persistent memory* section is set to signal new FW available, and the program then restarts into the bootloader. The bootloader checks the flag and sees that an update is available, erases the contents of the *Main program* and copies the content of *New firmware* into the *Main program* section. The flag is cleared, and it then branches into the now updated main program. This works perfectly, and is robust against power loss or errors at any point in the prosess.

I want to do a very similar implementation on the STM32. However, this time around my Main program uses a few dependencies that take up quite a lot of flash memory. For instance a printf implementation that is very useful, but takes up quite a lot of space (relative to what I have available). These libraries will naturally be used, probably unchanged, in all future versions of the program.

My question is whether it is possible to relocate certain parts of code that will be used, unchanged, by all future versions of the program, to a separate (fifth) section in the flash memory. This would save space in that (for instance) the printf library would only be allocated once in flash, instead of having to be included within the main program and all updates.

Is there a way to do this, if so, how? And is it a viable way to go in your opinion? Any pitfalls that must be avoided?

Comment: What if you get a power loss during the erase + write cycle to the "persistent memory" flag?

Comment: Shouldn't be a problem. If we fail to set the flag after downloading the FW the Main program will be unaffected and will in the worst case just download the new FW again, redundantly. If we are mid-erase of the Main program and get a power loss, the bootloader will just start over with the erase+copy operation once power is back, as the flag is still set.

Comment: Ok so you use an active low flag and when zero you launch the bootloader?

Comment: The bootloader is at address 0 in flash, so it always launches first on any resets (startup or otherwise). It checks the flag (which is indeed active low) and branches to the main program if the flag is cleared (i.e. 0xFF). If it is set (0x00), the bootloader erases the Main program area and copies all bytes from the new FW area, then only clears the flag when this is completed.

Comment: You could try to make the main part a bit smaller, and create there a new flashable unit. You could locate the library there. The problem might be functions/drivers/interfaces/buffers used internally within printf, e.g. to actually access the output device, e.g. UART driver or such, if these are within your main app. Depending on your build system and compiler/linker, they object code could move. If you can change the lib, maybe you can make an symbol (func-pointer) table within startup, like one would do with dynamic library loading (DLL/so).